# How to handle proxy via c#

Tags: c#, security, internet-explorer, c#-4.0, proxy

I have a Word AddIn written in C#, which connects to the server to get data via a  httpwebrequest

When the user switches from one proxy (Home) to another proxy (office), the addin still memorises the old proxy which is home proxy and it is not able to connect to the server in this case.

So I open fiddler to check why it fails. Then my addin starts working.

I checked the proxy settings with fiddler open, look, it is changed to "Use a proxy server for your LAN"

I want to do the same thing in my code, use the proxy setting from IE settings and use it in my code.

Do you know how to accomplish this?

Comment: Have you figured out this? I am looking to use proxy setting from IE settings, too, especially how to get proxy server from Automation script.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work; add the WebProxy to the request like so:

```
        var proxyObj = new WebProxy("ipaddress:port");
        proxyObj.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;
        using (var webClient = new WebClient())
        {
            webClient.Proxy = proxyObj;
            webClient.DownloadFile(remoteFileAddress, localFileAddress);
        }
```